# jQuery - rule for "does not contain element"

Tags: jquery

I want to create a rule to target the `a` element in the following:

```
<ul id="root">
   <li>
      <a href="item.html">Root Menu Item</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

However this should not apply if the `li` element contains another `ul` element, e.g:

```
<ul id="root">
   <li>
      <a href="#">Sub Menu</a>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <a href="item.html">Sub Menu Item</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I have created the event as required but need it to only work on the "root" menu items.

I know I can just add an id attribute to target the desired element only but the menu plugin that my client has installed is not easily configurable.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you're matching the `a` do this:

```
var result  = $('#root > li:not(:has(ul)) > a');
```

- http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

If you want to allow deeper nested `<ul>` elements, and just want to check to make sure only the direct children don't have a `<ul>`, you could do this:

```
var result  = $('#root > li:not(:has(> ul)) > a');
```

---

**EDIT:**

To have more than one selector at the same time, separate them with a comma inside the quotes:

```
var result  = $('#root > li:not(:has(> ul)) > a, #someOtherElement');
```

Comment: Cheers, I'm matching on the "a" tag. This has worked perfectly.

Comment: How can I do "OR" conditions for my click function, for example if I wanted to have the same click function for another tag?

Comment: @GSTAR - Glad it worked. I'm going to give one more update that will allow you to have deeper nested `<ul>` elements if needed.

Comment: @GSTAR - You can separate selectors with a comma (inside the quotes). I'll update with an example.

Comment: @GSTAR - Just want to make sure of one thing. You don't have more than one `<ul id="root">` do you?

Comment: By the way what benefit is there of using the > (child selector?) I noticed it still works if you don't put in the child selector.

Comment: @GSTAR - I wasn't sure of your entire markup. It is probably not necessary in your case. Say if at the top level you had an `<a>` element that didn't have any `<ul>` siblings, but it did have a `<div>` sibling, and that `<div>` had a `<ul>` descendant, then with the first selector, the `<a>` would not be selected, because `:has()` searches deep into the descendants. So if you wanted that `<a>` to be selected given that scenario, you would use the second example I gave, because the `:has()` would only match `<ul>` elements that are direct descendants of the `<li>`.

Comment: @GSTAR - ...consider this example that uses `has(> ul)`: http://jsfiddle.net/wkCvV/ It alerts 1 result, because I wrapped the nested `<ul>` in a `<div>`. Remove the `<div>` tags and click **Run** at the top, and it alerts 0. Or keep the `<div>` but do `has(ul)`, and the result will be 0, when you may want 1.

Comment: Patrick, thank you very much! You opened up my world of jQuery selectors greatly.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#root a').click(function(e) {
    if ( $(this).parents('ul').length > 1 ) {
       e.preventDefault(); // cancel action for anchors inside of #root who have multiple parent list elements 
    }
});
```

Change logic per requirement.

Comment: Cheers. Is e.preventDefault(); the same as return false;? 
Which is faster?

Comment: `return false` causes the function to cease. `preventDefault` is the standard DOM method. I would just use the latter, I would think `return false` is "faster" because you exit immediately whereas `preventDefault` still does some things internally.